# how this program creates zombie process?

Tags: c, linux, process, zombie-process

How the below program works and create a Zombie process under linux?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main ()
{
  pid_t child_pid;

  child_pid = fork ();
  if (child_pid > 0) {
    sleep (60);
  }
  else {
    exit (0);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It creates children and doesn't wait (with one of the wait* system call) for them.  And zombies are just that: children that the parents hasn't waited yet, the kernel has to maintain some information for them -- mainly the exit status -- in order to be able to return it to the parent.

Comment: Agree, while the future zombie is waiting the parent dies. :)

Comment: @Rolice, same thing as to Cicida: it is the parent (which gets the pid of the child as result of fork) which sleeps, the child (which gets 0 as result of fork) returns immediately. (And your use of wait to for the sleeping process in a context where a wait system call is missing could be confusing).

Comment: @anishsane, zombies are dead (terminated) but there parent isn't and hasn't waited for them. Orphans aren't dead, but there parent is, they have been adopted by process 1 which will wait for them.

Comment: Then, in his example, the `if` block is child & is alive for 60 ms, whereas the parent has already exited. Is the child not orphan process?

Comment: @anishsane The if block is the parent (return value of fork() > 0)

Answer (score 1):

The `setsid()` command is missing.

Every *nix process produces an exit status that must be reaped. This is supposed to be reaped by the parent process using a wait() statement, if the child is supposed to terminate first.

The `setsid()` command switches the parent process to init when the parent terminates before the child process.

Root should be able to remove zombies from the process list using kill -9. Inexperienced programmers sometimes omit `setsid()`, which will hide bugs that produce errors that would otherwise clog the disk drive.

In days of old, the system administrator would use zombies to identify inexperienced programmers that need additional training to produce good code.

The exit status harvested by init is sent to syslog when the kernel terminates a program prematurely. That exit status is used to identify the nature of the bug that caused the early termination (error conditions not handled by the programmer).

Exit status reported in this way becomes part of the syslog or klog files, which are commonly used to debug code.